# bootstrap website slider to work movie in background

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, slider

i am looking for some kind of slider for my website like skype.com or other websites which shows movies effect.

any one knows how to make banners like that in responsive website?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's all fine and dandy, but the video is disabled on skype.com for mobile devices and only an image is shown. Whereas for bigger screens it shows the video tag which plays in the background.

Why not inspect the website with developer tools and see how they have done it. Seems simple to me, it's all about the structure of the elements and the classes applied.